# Localstack mess up Lambda environment variables which contains : (colon)

Tags: linux, docker, environment-variables, localstack

I am using localstack with docker-compose.

```
version: '3.8'

localstack:
container_name: localstack
image: localstack:0.12.11
volumes:
  - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
ports:
  - "4566:4566"
environment:
  SERVICES: sqs,lambda
  LAMBDA_EXECUTOR: docker
  DOCKER_HOST: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
  DEBUG: "1"
  ENFORCE_IAM: "1"
healthcheck:
  test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "awslocal sqs list-queues && awslocal lambda list-functions" ]
  interval: 10s
```

Using terraform 0.11.15 I am setting the environment variable for the lambda as follow

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {

  function_name = "lambda"
  role          = ""

  filename         = "${data.archive_file.pack_lambda_code.output_path}"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.pack_lambda_code.output_base64sha256}"

  handler = "#HIDDEN#"
  runtime = "dotnetcore3.1"
  timeout = 60

  environment {
    variables = {
      CategoryId = "123"
      "Types:Apples" = "ABC"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to pass an env var as a map into the Lambda, that's why I am declaring "Types: Apples" like that

The problem is that Localstack passes this env var to the new docker container in which the Lambda will live with this arg `-e Types:Apples=$Types: Apples` which result in the following value of the env var inside the Lambda

```
Types
     Apples = :Apples
```

Searching for a solution/workaround